# Beautiful Soup не парсит всю страницу

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Хочу спарсить при помощи Beautiful Soup наименования iphone с этой страницы "https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914/seriya-iphone=iphone-11-pro-max/diagonal-ekrana=62-i-bolee/vstroennaya-pamyat=256gb"

Например в Эльдорадо у меня получилось, но при таком же коде парсинг Мвидео происходит не всей страницы. В результате не видно даже названий iphone пример:(Смартфон Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max 256GB Midnight Green MWHM2RU/A), хотя я прописал в примере, чтобы парсил всю страницу.
В чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста?

UPD:понял, что тут идет загрузка динамического контента. Буду копать в эту сторону. Если у кого есть информация/ помощь / примеры, то это будет к месту!

```
#посмотреть название айфона
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914/seriya-iphone=iphone-11-pro-max/diagonal-ekrana=62-i-bolee/vstroennaya-pamyat=256gb/'
r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)

soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
iph_names = soup.find_all()
for name in iph_names:
    print (name)
```

Comment: а где у вас поиска? он у вас пустой сейчас

Comment: В find_all надо прописать, что вы хотите найти

Comment: @danilshik  Если ничего там не писать, то он должен парсить все коды html, которые есть на этой странице. По крайней мере я так делал с Эльдорадо. Но в случае с Мвидео нет строки 
  '<a data-v-7806fa87="" data-v-72e91d27="" href="/products/smartfon-apple-iphone-11-pro-max-256gb-midnight-green-mwhm2ru-a-30045454" class="product-title product-title--clamp">
  Смартфон Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max 256GB Midnight Green MWHM2RU/A
</a>'

Comment: @SergeyT а вы уверены, что эти данные не подгружаются через Ajax?

Comment: @danilshik Не могу сказать точно, я только учусь. Пока мне кажется проблема из-за динамического контента.

Comment: @SergeyT у вас контент подгружается через Ajax, его не спарсить через Bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данном сайте данные действительно подгружаются через Ajax. Соответственно необходимо загрузить страницу, выполнить скрипты и получить контент. Я бы использовал для этого смесь Selenium и BS, если это необходимо. Код бы выглядел примерно таким образом:

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
        from selenium import webdriver
        url = "https://www.mvideo.ru/smartfony-i-svyaz-10/smartfony-205/f/category=iphone-914/seriya-iphone=iphone-11-pro-max/diagonal-ekrana=62-i-bolee/vstroennaya-pamyat=256gb"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(config.safe_delay)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BS(html, "html.parser")
        iph_names = soup.find_all()
        for name in iph_names:
           print (name)
```

Такой код будет более требователен к ресурсам системы, но по скорости работы системы сильно отличаться не будет, т.к. пока BS парсерит 1-страницу сайта, Selenium может загружать следующую.

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.
Добавлю только, что необходимо будет скачать webdriver chrome - 1 ссылка в гугле
и строку в коде написать в следующем формате, где у вас будет расположен chromedriver

"driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")"

Comment: только выдает ошибку на ("module 'config' has no attribute 'safe_delay')
Можете пояснить эта строка в коде для чего time.sleep(config.safe_delay)?
Понимаю, что это задержка по времени, но если поясните, будет замечательно.

Comment: Сафе делэй это время через которое будет произведён парсеринг. Вы можете заменить safe_delay на время в секундах или добавить в ваш config файл переменную safe_delay и присвоить ей некоторое значение (порядка 10 - 15 сек)